# A question about fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-mechanics

A water pipe has an inner diameter of 20 mm. How many liters of soap runs through the tube in ten minutes when the speed is 1.5 meters per second

what i know so far:
Q = flow rate is in cubic metres per second (or minute, etc). It means the volume of flow that passes through something in unit time. "Unit" time, for example if I say 10m3/s, it means 10 cubic metres of something passed through in 1 second.

Now the formula Q=AV (known as continuity equation) is used to find Q. But how do i find it

is this the answer: 3,14 * 20*20 / 4 = 100 =

3.14 * 100 = 314 = 0,314 meters

0,314 meters * 1.5 m/s = 0,471

How i calculated it

The area of the pipe is 0.314 m2. The flow rate can be found in 1.5m/s using the formula:

Q = Av

Q = (0.314 m2)(1.5m/s)

Q = 0.471 m3/s

The flow rate can be converted to liters per second using: 1 m3/s = 1000 L/s.

Q = 47.1 L/s then i just multiplie this by 60 * 10 ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question... What methods have you tried to solve it?

Comment: This may only need continuity as there is no information about friction / pressure drop.

Comment: your answer is in our question. volume = A*v =1.5*10*pi*0.2^2/4

Comment: So A is area which you have in terms of diameter and a well known constant... and V is velocity which you also have, you don't expect us to have to finish it from there do you?

Comment: 20mm is not 2 metres

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer because it answers the question, but I'm still unclear as to where you're having trouble...

You are trying to obtain how many liters (volume) go through the pipe over ten minutes (time).

You know the continuity equation $Q = A \cdot v$. $Q$ is a measure of volume over time. So, for example, if you know that $Q = 1\text{ liter/second}$, I hope it's clear how to calculate how many liters you get in ten minutes.

So we now know the first thing you need to do is calculate $Q$. Thankfully, you know the speed $v$ (a given in the question), and you have the diameter, so calculating the area $A$ shouldn't be too hard either.

Comment: is this the answer: 3,14 * 20*20 / 4 = 100 =

3.14 * 100 = 314 = 0,314 meters

0,314 meters * 1.5 m/s = 0,471

How i calculated it

The area of the pipe is 0.314 m2. The flow rate can be found in 1.5m/s using the formula:

Q = Av

Q = (0.314 m2)(1.5m/s)

Q = 0.471 m3/s

The flow rate can be converted to liters per second using: 1 m3/s = 1000 L/s.

Q = 47.1 L/s then i just multiplie this by 60 * 10 ?

Comment: @ThorLie remember that the pipe's diameter is 20mm. That's 2cm. Does 0.314m^2 seem like a reasonable area for the pipe? Other than that, yes, your work is correct.